# Exclude id in rails scope

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, scope

How can I exclude some items in this scope:

`scope :within_category, ->(category) { joins(:category).where(:categories => { :id => category }) }`

like this:

```
scope :within_category, ->(category, item_type) { joins(:category).where(:categories => { :id => category }, :id NOT IN item_type.id) }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
scope :within_category, ->(category, item_type) { joins(:category).where(:categories => { :id => category }).where(self.arel_table[:id].not_in(item_type.id) }
```